# How to represent inf or -inf in Cython with numpy?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy, cython

I am building an array with cython element by element. I'd like to store the constant `np.inf` (or `-1 * np.inf`) in some entries. However, this will require the overhead of going back into Python to look up `inf`. Is there a `libc.math` equivalent of this constant? Or some other value that could easily be used that's equivalent to `(-1*np.inf)` and can be used from Cython without overhead?

*EDIT* example, you have:

```
cdef double value = 0
for k in xrange(...):
  # use -inf here -- how to avoid referring to np.inf and calling back to python?
  value = -1 * np.inf
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no literal for it, but `float` can parse it from a string:

```
>>> float('inf')
inf
>>> np.inf == float('inf')
True
```

Alternatively, `math.h` *may* (almost certainly will) declare a macro that evaluates to inf, in which case you can just use that:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    float INFINITY
```

---

(There's no clean way to check if INFINITY is defined in pure Cython, so if you want to cover all your bases you'll need to get hacky. One way of doing it is to create a small C header, say `fallbackinf.h`:

```
#ifndef INFINITY
#define INFINITY 0
#endif
```

And then in your .pyx file:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    float INFINITY

cdef extern from "fallbackinf.h":
    pass

inf = INFINITY if INFINITY != 0 else float('inf')
```

(You can't assign to INFINITY, because it's an rvalue. You could do away with the ternary operator if you #defined INFINITY as 1.0/0.0 in your header, but that might raise SIGFPE, depending on your compiler.)

This is definitely in the realm of cargo cult optimisation, though.)

Comment: but if I use `float` within a Cython loop, will that involve calling back to Python? I edited my answer to give an example.

Comment: Ultimately that calls `PyFloat_AsDouble` every time, which isn't *that* slow, but not something you want to do more often than necessary; assign it to a constant once, outside the loop. But I've updated my answer with a different, compile-time method.

Comment: Thanks! your `cdef extern...` works great. Are there systems/conditions where it might not work, or should it work on any python distribution / OS?

Comment: The INFINITY macro was added in C99; if your math.h is older, it's not guaranteed to be there (though it probably still will be). In practice, it should be fine.

Comment: Last question: is it possible to programmatically check for INFINITY (if it exists) through Cython and if not, default to `float('inf')`?

Comment: Not cleanly. I've added what I believe to be the easiest way to my answer.

Answer (score 20):

The recommended way of doing this in Cython is:

```
from numpy.math cimport INFINITY
```

Note, that this is a "cimport" rather than a regular import. This is Cython's official wrapper around NumPy's `npymath`.

Comment: I get the error `fatal error: 'numpy/npy_math.h' file not found`. Anyone else get this?

Comment: @hlin117, nope. Probably something wrong with your setup. This answer is still the recommended way to get infinity.

Comment: Can you provide a cite for "the recommended way..."?

Comment: Are you being overly pedantic? If you want to use Numpy's stuff, then this a cleaner way than using a cdef extern. If you want to use math.h, then it looks like `from libc.math cimport INFINITY` is now available, which could also work. Both of these options are better than the other two answers given, especially if you are working on any modern platform.

Comment: Also, see the example of using `cimport` here: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/external.html#calling-c-functions

Answer (score 4):

You can use Numpy's math library, [see here for what's available](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.coremath.html):

```
cdef extern from "numpy/npy_math.h":
    double inf "NPY_INFINITY"
```

When building the Cython extension module, you need to specify the correct include directory and library to link:

```
>>> from numpy.distutils.misc_util import get_info
>>> get_info('npymath')
{'define_macros': [], 
 'libraries': ['npymath', 'm'], 
 'library_dirs': ['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/lib'], 
 'include_dirs': ['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include']}
```

The information obtained from that function can be passed onto Python distutils, or whatever build system you use.