# Pandas rolling returns NaN when infinity values are involved

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When using `rolling` on a series that contains `inf` values the result contains `NaN` even if the operation is well defined, like `min` or `max`. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.inf, 5, 6])
print(s.rolling(window=3).min())
```

This gives:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
dtype: float64
```

while I expected

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    3.0
5    5.0
```

Computing the minimum of the series directly works as expected:

```
s.min()  # 1.0
```

What is the reason for additional `NaN` values being introduced?

---

Python 3.8.1, pandas 1.0.2

Answer (score 5):

`np.inf` is explicitly converted to `np.NaN` in [pandas/core/window/rolling.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/core/window/rolling.py#L276-L279)

```
# Convert inf to nan for C funcs
inf = np.isinf(values)
if inf.any():
    values = np.where(inf, np.nan, values)
```

[How to represent inf or -inf in Cython with numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050549/how-to-represent-inf-or-inf-in-cython-with-numpy) gives information on why they had to do this.

---

You'd find the exact same behavior if you had `NaN` instead of `np.inf`. It can be difficult to get your output because `min_counts` will throw away those intermediate groups because they lack sufficient observations. One clean "hack" is to replace `inf` with the biggest value you can, which should be rather safe taking `'min'`.

```
import numpy as np
s.replace(np.inf, np.finfo('float64').max).rolling(3).min()

#0    NaN
#1    NaN
#2    1.0
#3    2.0
#4    3.0
#5    5.0
#dtype: float64
```

Comment: Given the link to the source code I see why this result emerges but I don't understand why it is converted in the first place. `inf` is defined in the floating point standard so why would it cause any trouble? I read the question you linked but couldn't find the relevant information.

Comment: @a_guest I don't know enough about cython to say exactly why this is done, perhaps there's a better link somewhere else I can see if I can find.