# How to stop pandas rolling from casting infinity to nan?

Tags: python, pandas, casting, nan, rolling-computation

I have the following operation:

```
  df["sd"] = df.groupby("vid")["col"].apply(
    lambda x: x.rolling(
      window=50, min_periods=12
    ).apply(lambda y: _custom_stdev_func(y, 12))
  )

def _sd_na(x):
  return np.nanstd(x, ddof=1)

def _custom_stdev_func(x, min_observations):
  num_samples = np.sum(~np.isnan(x))
  return _sd_na(x) if num_samples >= min_observations else np.nan
```

It's possible that `df["col"]` may be +/-`inf`  values, however, because `rolling` will explicitly cast it to NaN (see [Pandas rolling returns NaN when infinity values are involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766199/pandas-rolling-returns-nan-when-infinity-values-are-involved)) its entries will be discarded in the `np.nanstd` call. I do not want to discard infinity values. If it's not discarded, then `np.nanstd` will return `nan` if it sees an infinity value which is the behavior that I want.

Is there a way to stop `rolling` from doing the explicit cast? If not, is the only other approach here to write my own custom rolling function, which may not be as performant as pandas?

Comment: please tag all python related questions with the [python] tag

Comment: One idea I've thought of is a bit hacky. fill `df["col"]` infinity values with `sys.float_info.max`. this should cause std to be evalutaed to INF and then I can cast it to nan in the std function.

Comment: actually std will evaluate to nan in this case, so I don't think I need to convert inf to nan after the std computation, so i think filling with float max by itself will work

Comment: @u2j4: have you tried create dummy columns where inf value is converted to NaN? That is a simplier approach

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas 2.1.3 the standard approach appears to do what you want

```py
s = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, np.inf])
print(list(s.rolling(window=3).apply(np.nanstd)))
[nan, nan, 0.0, 0.4714045207910317, nan]
```

There is peculiar behaviour if min() is used on the same series:

```py
print(list(s.rolling(window=3).min()))
[nan, nan, 1.0, 1.0, nan]
```

I'd expect the final nan value to be a 1

Both of these behaviours are altered by setting min_periods=1

```py
print(list(s.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).apply(np.nanstd)))
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4714045207910317, 0.5]
print(list(s.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).min()))
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

min() now gives the expected result in the last entry, while
nanstd appears to discard the inf value

This is possibly buggy behaviour in Pandas - I can't see why
changing min_periods should change the value of the final entry
in these lists

Incidentally, it's not that .rolling() is casting inf to nan.
Something else happening, maybe, when the summary functions are applied:

```py
print([list(r) for r in s.rolling(window=3)])
[[1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0, inf]]
```